# imageview animation that changes leftMargin

Tags: android

I have been working on an app for android that has balls being shot at an avatar. I have an animation that I defined in an xml file and I want it change a variable during the animation to the imageview performing the animation's current x coordinate or what it's leftMargin would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView view=(ImageView)findviewByid("Your Image id");
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest  , 0, yDest );
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setFillAfter( true );
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Use this it will work